# How do the meanings of "alloi" and "heteroi" compare in Matthew 16:14?

Tags: matthew

**Matthew 16:14**

> And they said, "Some say John the Baptist, others **[alloi]** say Elijah, and others **[heteroi]** Jeremiah or one of the prophets". ESV My brackets.

I think that since  "alloi" and "heteroi" appear here  together, direct comparison between them  maybe facilitated.

On this site "Why was Jeremiah named in Matthew 16:14?" is related but does not focus on what I ask here.

Comment: use wiktionary and this LSJ site. It means other (some else), and another of same kind. https://lsj.gr/wiki/%E1%BC%95%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82

Comment: @Michael16 Matt 8:21 If most disciples are staying but "another/heteros" wants to leave they would be a different kind. Matt 11:16 The children separate into different/heterois groups. Those that want to play and those that don't want to join in. Matt 12:45 The 7 other spirits are different/hetera if more evil than the first?

Comment: one of another group, meaning diff/another. So, Some said John, others said Elijah, another(a diff group of 'others'; ie a diff other) said Jeremiah. Spirit brings another 7 spirits. Children calling to another playmates. Think about heterosexual; a different other in sex; Homosexual- exactly same sex.

Comment: As an exercise, I actually looked at all the instances of allos and heteros and concluded that the original distinction between these two words had largely (not totally) disappeared by the time of the NT.  That is, in many places, such as in Matt 16:14 they are used interchangeably.

Comment: @Dottard Trench devotes four pages on allos/heteros differences. I quote : Romans 7:23  "I see another law" his comment- "a law quite different from the law of spirit of life, even a law of sin and death..." Also Trench: Mark 16:12 hetera-the word indicating the mighty change which passed upon Him at his resurrection, as an anticipation  at his Transfiguration." hetera morphe

Comment: _Hetero_ is a 'more distant other' rather than others of a same group. (See Galatians 1:7/8 : 'another' gospel _hetero_ which is not 'similar' _alloi_.) Therefore the scope of participation, in Matthew 6:14, widens from others (of a similar ilk) to others (of another way of thinking). – Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to see the two words contrasted, in my own view, is Galatians 1:7 and 8 where Paul calls the false gospel being preached at Galatia as *hetero*.

He says that that gospel is 'another' (*hetero*) gospel but is not a 'similar' (*allo*) gospel.

It is another kind of gospel which is not a valid alternative to *the* gospel.

Thus *hetero* is of a similar category of existence. But *allo* is a close companion.

Thus in Matthew 16:14 the comparison is widening from those *allo* who - correctly - saw that Jesus has strong connection (see Malachi 3:1,2 - Messenger of Preparation and Messenger of the Covenant) to John the Baptist. Then 'other' saw a connection (understandably) with Elijah (who prefigured John) but 'others' *hetero*, making a much wider comparison and being wider of the mark in their categorisation, suggested Jeremiah or (even more vaguely) 'one of the prophets'.

The list widens from a wise interpretation to an obscure reference to a merely vague suggestion.

Thus those who *speak* these alternatives are categorised according to the *character* of their concepts.